# TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str , python using collections.defaultdict(set)

Tags: python, python-2.7, port-scanning

I wrote a port scanner which basically compares a new scan result to a previous scan result and then finds what ports changed/got_added/got_deleted .

The method which compares the port changes looks like:

```
    def comp_ports(self,filename):
          try:
                f = open(filename)
                self.prev_report = pickle.load(f) # NmapReport

                self.old_port_dict = collections.defaultdict(set)
                for s in self.prev_report.hosts:
                     for x in s.get_open_ports():
                          self.old_port_dict[s.address].add(x)

                self.new_port_dict = collections.defaultdict(set)
                for s in self.report.hosts:
                     for x in s.get_open_ports():
                        self.new_port_dict[s.address].add(x)

                hosts = sorted(set(self.old_port_dict) | set(self.new_port_dict))

                scan_same = dict()
                scan_new = dict()
                scan_del = dict()


prev_set = set(self.prev_report.hosts)
            new_set = set(self.report.hosts)

            scan_same = prev_set & new_set
            scan_new = new_set - prev_set
            scan_del = prev_set - new_set

            print()
            print('-' * 10, 'Same')
            for host, ports in scan_same.items():
                print(host, ':')
                for port in ports:
                     print(':::', port[0], '/', port[1])

            print()
            print('*' * 10, 'Added')
            for host, ports in scan_new().items():
                print(host, ':')
                for port in ports:
                      print(':::', port[0], '/', port[1])

            print()
            print('=' * 10, 'Deleted')
            for host, ports in scan_del().items():
                print(host, ':')
                for port in ports:
                       print(':::', port[0], '/', port[1])

      except Exception as l:
             print l
             raise
```

Based on the answers, but this throws the new exception :

```
'set' object has no attribute 'items'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "portwatch.py", line 316, in <module>
    report.comp_ports(config.get('system','scan_directory') + '/nmap-report-old.pkl')
  File "portwatch.py", line 159, in comp_ports
    for host, ports in scan_same.items():
AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'items'
```

How do i iterate?

Comment: What is the type of `self.prev_report.hosts` and `self.report.hosts`?

Comment: @fjarri both are list

Comment: Well, here's your problem then. You're trying to index a list with a string in `self.prev_report.hosts[host]` and `self.report.hosts[host]`

Comment: @fjarri yep.. and how do i get over this ? coz i need to compare each `host`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering the following code you posted (which is where the exception is raised):

```
for host in hosts:
    scan_same[host] = self.prev_report.hosts[host] & self.report.hosts[host]
    scan_new[host]  = self.report.hosts[host] - self.prev_report.hosts[host]
    scan_del[host]  = self.prev_report.hosts[host] - self.report.hosts[host]
```

You seem to want to get the set of common hosts and the sets of hosts only found in each of the two reports. Your code was almost right, you just unnecessarily used iteration and indexing where the set operations get you exactly what you want immediately:

```
prev_set = set(self.prev_report.hosts)
new_set = set(self.report.hosts)

scan_same = prev_set & new_set
scan_new = new_set - prev_set
scan_del = prev_set - new_set
```

Comment: oh okay.. cool i get your point. while it goes down the print loop i again face 
`('----------', 'Same')
'set' object has no attribute 'items'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "portwatch.py", line 316, in <module>
    report.comp_ports(config.get('system','scan_directory') + '/nmap-report-old.pkl')
  File "portwatch.py", line 159, in comp_ports
    for host, ports in scan_same.items():
AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'items'`

Comment: how do i iterate on the scan_same , scan_new & scan_del

Comment: Read about [the `set` class](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set), it's not hard and very useful. Iteration is done with `for`, just like lists.

Comment: For additional questions, please open separate questions. Also, if this has answered your original question, please accept it!

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that you are using `host` (a `str`) as index of your `self.report.hosts` which is a `list`. You can only use `str` indices on `dict` but not on `list` objects.

Comment: oh thank you, i understand . Please see my comment on taleinat's answer

Answer (score 0):

You have been forcing the port dictionaries into sets. If you iterate over a dictionary it will return the keys only, so you enter up with a set of keys, most likely strings.

You might be happier when using `.values()` or `.items()` on the dicts first.

Comment: I changed  
         `prev_set = set(self.prev_report.hosts)
            new_set = set(self.report.hosts)

            scan_same = prev_set & new_set
            scan_new = new_set - prev_set
            scan_del = prev_set - new_set`

but i receive 
`'set' object has no attribute 'items'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "portwatch.py", line 316, in <module>
    report.comp_ports(config.get('system','scan_directory') + '/nmap-report-old.pkl')
  File "portwatch.py", line 159, in comp_ports
    for host, ports in scan_same.items():
AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'items'`

Comment: Not on the set, on the dict.

Comment: which dict ? coz i am storing it in set i suppose , edited my question . See the question

Comment: It is called `old_port_dict` and a `defaultdict`.